# Access denied after changed password with spring boot security JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm implementing spring boot security for my application. The login function works fine, but somehow whenever I test the change-password function, it's always failed, I checked in the database the password has been updated with the new HashString, but I cannot login with both old-password and new-password. Please help !

Here is the change-password API

```
@PutMapping("/reset-password")
    public  ResponseEntity resetPassword(@RequestBody String password){
        //extract user name
        String username =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                .getPrincipal().toString();
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(applicationUser == null ){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Could not find UserName");
        }

        applicationUser.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password));

        applicationUserRepo.save(applicationUser);
        Logs log = new Logs (TimeConverter.getVietnamCurrentTime(),"PASSWORD", "User", applicationUser.getUsername(), applicationUser.getUsername() );
        logsRepo.save(log);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Password changed successfully!");
    }
```

Here is my implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }


    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFilter

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("fucked");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth)  {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","*");

    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.getWriter().write("blalfaf");
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
    addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

instead of just

```
    addFilter(....
```

in your WebSecurity.configure(.....

This will put your own filter before the original UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. Maybe your filter is last in line and the login is failing before.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but it doesn't work in this case. it's hard to know at which stage the request gets denied.